# Oracle Forms FRM-47100: Cannot read image file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to display a jpg in my form. In "WHEN-NEW-BLOCK-INSTANCE" trigger of my datablock, this is my code:

```
     READ_IMAGE_FILE ('/home/oracle/program/photos/qrcd.jpg',
                      'JPG',
                      'DATABLOCK.QRCD');
```

My image item's Image Format is BMP. I put qrcd.jpg file to /home/oracle/program/photos directory. When I run the program, I get error message "FRM-47100: Cannot read image file /home/oracle/program/photos/qrcd.jpg."

(I copied this issues from another image item that is displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized that my jpg filesize 1.76 KB (it is too small) It is discomposed. I refreshed jpg file and it worked.